# Unexpected Text Widget behavior in loop

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, tk-toolkit, subprocess

Please refer the code below:
I am able to print the two print statements (at #1 and #2) on real time basis(line by line). However the text widget appears only after the execution of the subprocess csh script.

**When I am able to print the values received from stdout of subprocess, why is it not displayed on text widget?**

```
#!/tools//python/2.7.2/bin/python -u

import os
import ttk 
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess
import sys

t = Tk()      
t.title('New title')
t.geometry('800x1000-5+40')
t.state('normal')
little = Label(t, text="OUTPUT LOG").grid(column = 0, row = 0)
log = Text(t, state='normal', width=115, height=150, wrap='none')
log.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

test=subprocess.Popen("tem",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
#tem is a csh file which print number from 1 to 1000

#stdout
cnt = 0.0
while True:
    line = test.stdout.readline()
        cnt += 1
        if line == "":
            break
        else:   
        log['state'] = 'normal'
        log.insert(cnt,line)
                print 'line #' #1
                print line     #2
log['state'] = 'disabled'

t.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that events *must* be being serviced in order for the display to update. This is fundamental to the way that Tk (and hence Tkinter) works. The easiest method in Python is probably to put the reading from the subprocess in its own thread that then sends each line in a message to the main GUI thread for display.